# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I m using in C# Code

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDivisionId.SelectedValue);
```

at that time this type of error accrued..

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.IConvertible'
```

how can i solve it ?

Please help

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your `ddlDivisionId.SelectedValue` is returning a `DataRowView`. I assume you bound a DataTable or similar to your dropdown list (assuming that is what we are looking at).

In this case you will need to treat the `ddlDivisionId.SelectedValue` as a DataRowView (probably casting to that object first) to get the value out of it... I assume something like:

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)ddlDivisionId.SelectedValue)["id"]);
```

Here you should replace "id" with whatever the name of your field is in your datatable that you want to get out as an integer.

Comment: ya i m using DataTable to fill grid.In this case I want to (ddlDivisionId.SelectedValue) this dropdown value on selectedIndex changed.

Comment: my dropdown field name is 'DivisionId'in database..so here what i Put instead of ["id"] ?

Comment: int i = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)ddlDivisionId.SelectedValue)["id"]); after use this i get error : 
id is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table.

Comment: 2nd answer show in my inbox but i cant open 2nd answer..so plz post again

Comment: I've updated with a note about "id". Basically that is the field name in your table that you are trying to access.

Comment: For some reasons, for some `ComboBox`es SelectedValue is a string value, for others are `DataRowView`. The order of assigning `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` and `DataSource` is right this way, but I don't know why, in some cases the type is changed, and debugger does not reveal it. So, I have to check first of all the type of SelectedValue.

Answer (score 4):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDivisionId.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

add .ToString in last it will work

Answer (score 1):

If you fill combo box,
Move first line to last:
Before

```
cbo.DataSource = dt; // this line
cbo.DisplayMember = "name";
cbo.ValueMember = "id";
```

After

```
cbo.DisplayMember = "name";
cbo.ValueMember = "id";
cbo.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code I was have the same problem and I get it solved by this code

```
public Items_form()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  comboBoxItemSizeCat.DataSource = SCC.AllSizeCategories();
  comboBoxItemSizeCat.DisplayMember = "Size Category";
  comboBoxItemSizeCat.ValueMember = "num";
}
private void comboBoxItemSizeCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 int i;
 Int32.TryParse(comboBoxItemSizeCat.SelectedValue.ToString(),out i);
 
 comboBoxItemSize.DataSource = SC.AllSize_accordingto_size_cat(i); 
 comboBoxItemSize.DisplayMember = "Size Name";
 comboBoxItemSize.ValueMember = "Size Code";



}
```