# How to loop through a table in c# and show the result in a datagridview?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a table and two inputs from the user.
I need to check those inputs with two columns in the table and if true then show that row in the datagridview.
Database is Ms Access.

```
private void btnresult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in crane_config.Tables["capacitytable"].Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToDouble(crane_config.Tables["capacitytable"].Columns[2]) > Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text))
            {
                if (Convert.ToDouble(crane_config.Tables["capacitytable"].Columns[3]) > Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text))
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = row;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I got this error :
Unable to cast object of type `System.Data.DataColumn` to type `System.IConvertible`

First check the input with "Radius" if it value in the table is greater then check the "capacity" with the second input. If the capacity is greater too, then show that row in a datagridview, otherwise go to next row. At the end it should show all the rows that pass the test.

```
| Index | Radius | Capacity (lbs) |
|:-----:|:------:|:--------------:|
| 19403 | 25     | 369500         |
| 19403 | 30     | 344900         |
| 19403 | 35     | 314700         |
| 19403 | 40     | 274600         |
| 19403 | 45     | 244000         |
| 19403 | 50     | 220300         |
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve (edit) question! E.g there are plenty of formatting option like paragraphs ;) (Noone read that textblock except as self-punishment.:( And **always** show data as [text tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)!

Comment: You literally expect us to read this wall of unformatted text? No, thanks.

Comment: Good improvement on question! Usually you should provide sample data and expected result. What was result of copy error message ro websearch? Hint: You can't convert all dattypes, some need 2 conversions.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I added the table that I am working on. I have searched for the error but I could not find something relevant.

Comment: Google "Unable to cast object of type System.Data.DataColumn to type System.IConvertible" [first hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338472/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-data-datacolumn-to-type-system-iconverti) is the usuall solution using a dataadapter (and sql code!), use this! For the record [second hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429139/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-data-datarowview-to-type-system-iconvert) shows how to avoid your error on conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, do you really want to loop?
I would pull the data from the table base on the criteria, and thus save the looping.

eg  somthing like this:

```
{
string strSQL = "SELECT [Index], Radius, Capacity FROM tblRdata " + "WHERE Radius > @PRad AND Capacity > @PCap " + "ORDER BY [Index],Radius,Capacity";
OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, new OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB));
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Prad", OleDbType.Double).Value = txtRadius.Text;
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@PCap", OleDbType.Double).Value = txtCapacity.Text;
OleDbDataAdapter dread = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
dread.Fill(rstData);
GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Also, the colums in a table are zero based. So, if that table really only has 3 columns?
Then you want .Columns[1] and [2], not 2 and 3 (first column is 0).

Now the table might be small, but say even for a small table in access of 50,000 rows, doing a data pull as opposed to looping the whole table would be faster.

I suppose it depends on where/when/how you have the table in your code loaded (dataset, or now the new entity framework perhaps?).

And if the table is already loaded? Then create what is called a "view" against that table - it will again allow filtering without looping.

So, you could use just these 2 or so lines against the existing table like this:

```
{
string strFilter = "Radius > " + txtRadius.Text + " AND Capacity > " + txtCapacity.Text;
DataView myview = new DataView(crane_config.Tables["capacitytable"], strFilter,
 "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

GridView1.DataSource = myview;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

So a view will let you filter against an existing table, and is less code, and the filter command is a string - no need for type conversions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried the second method, however, I got this error: for the last line of the code 'datagridview dose not contain a definition for databinding and no accessible extension method. If I comment out the last line it does not show anything in the datagridview @albert D. Kallal

Comment: It worked. I just had to change something in my code. That was awesome. @albert d. kallal